# How to resize font size if element overflows vertically?

Tags: html, css

On our cover page we want to display a title on a big font but if the title is too long it overflows and isn't displayed properly.

I came up with this js solution to resize the font when it overflows:

```
/** Checks if an element overflows. **/
let isOverflown = e => e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth || e.offsetHeight < e.scrollHeight;

/** Resizes an element's font size until it no longer overflows. **/
let resizeFont = $e => {
    let fontSize = parseInt($e.css('font-size'));
    const parent = $e.parent()[0];
    while (fontSize > 0 && isOverflown(parent)) $e.css('font-size', --fontSize + 'px');
}

resizeFont($('.title'));
```

And it does work for horizontal overflow, like in [this case](https://jsfiddle.net/kpagcha/e0qmktyf/4/) when you have a very long single word with no whitespaces. Just tweak the max width in the `.container` and you'll see the resize function at work.

However the same is not true for vertical overflow. Why isn't the overflow check function evaluating [this case](https://jsfiddle.net/kpagcha/e0qmktyf/6/) as no overflow when it obviously is overflowing?

edit: if I add `$e.css({'height': '100%'});` after the resizing function is run it does work but for some obscure reason the text is no longer aligned to the bottom on mobile. I tried using flexbox with `align-items: end` on the parent but then that messes up the resize function. Plus, mobile seems to ignore the flex alignment rule.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect element shows the `font-size` changing and the `height` and `width` are constant for `.title`. Please recheck.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding `height: 100%; width: 100%;` to `.title` and then using flexbox **after** the font resizing is finished in order to align the text to the bottom:

```
$e.css({'display': 'flex', 'align-items': 'flex-end'});
```